# Identify Brand of Bicycle

Tags: road-bike

I am wondering what brand of bicycle this is? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Any other markings on frame tubes?

Comment: Velobase has a [database of head tube badges](http://velobase.com/ListHeadBadges.aspx). I guessed the first letter is either an F or a T but it didn't match any of the brands beginning with those letters. It looks fairly modern, so I searched for all the badges from the 1990s onwards (there were only four pages), but that didn't work, either. You could look through all 53 pages of badges, if you're feeling keen! (It might be worth checking the 1980s, first.)

Comment: The nearest I could find was "franks forks" but they make motorbike forks so its not them.  Firefly bikes is not a match either.